# Display on a table only certain values from an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object, say,

```
var LocSpecs=[{Address:"xxxxxx",SF:"1,200",YearBuilt:"xxxx"},
              {Address:"xxxxxxx",SF:"1,950",YearBuilt:"xxxx"}.......}];
```

Over 200 key/values in the object.

I need to loop through and grab the values that meet a value and display said data on a table.

I get the `for()` and `if()`.  I just don't quite get the appending the table to show only the records that meet the criteria.

resulting table would display on a

```
document.getElementBy("xxxx").innerHTML=myTable;
```

Comment: document.getElementById() would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to display rows based on some value in the object.
Create a function that builds a row when condition is satisfied.

```
LocSpecs.forEach(function(elm) {
    if(elm.SF) { // your criteria
       addRow(elm);
    }
});

function addRow(elm) {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = elm.Address;
    cell2.innerHTML = elm.YearBuilt;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

I give you a ES6 alternative method to make a table. Using the DOMTableElement interface is inherently slower when used in JavaScript then adding pure HTML to the page and letting the browser's parser do it (That is what browsers are designed to do after all, parse and display HTML)

It uses Array.filter() to filter the records.
It uses Arrow functions to reduce the amount of code.
It uses Template strings to create the HTML for the table.

```js
var locSpecs=[ // some data with random addresses added
    {Address:"691 Union Street Herndon, VA 20170",SF:"1,950",YearBuilt:"1922"},
    {Address:"939 Laurel Drive Pawtucket, RI 02860",SF:"1,950",YearBuilt:"1922"},
    {Address:"176 Redwood Drive Ankeny, IA 50023",SF:"1,850",YearBuilt:"1932"},
    {Address:"621 Sycamore Lane Flint, MI 48504",SF:"1,750",YearBuilt:"1932"},
    {Address:"190 Canterbury Court Bountiful, UT 84010",SF:"1,350",YearBuilt:"1922"},
    {Address:"461 3rd Street West Coram, NY 11727",SF:"1,950",YearBuilt:"1922"}
]




function createTable(data,filter,cellOrder,elementID,title){
    // defined functions needed
    function createRow(record){     // create a row
        var str = "";               // string to hold the row HTML
        cellOrder.forEach(     // for each field in order
            // want it to look good so add the cell class and the field class
            name => str+=`<td class='${fieldClassPrefix+name}' >${record[name]}</td>`
        );
        return `<tr>${str}</tr>`; // wrap a row tab and return the new HTML for row
    }
    function createHeader(){  // created the header
        var str = ""
        cellOrder.forEach(name => str+= `<td class='${fieldClassPrefix+name}' >${name}</td>`);
        return `<thead><tr>${str}</tr></thead>`;
    }
    // define variableds 
    var HTML, tableContainerElement,fieldClassPrefix;  // you should not see any var tokens past this point
    
    HTML = "";  // string to hold the new table HTML
    fieldClassPrefix = "FF_"; // prfix for field class names
    // find the element that will contain the new table
    tableContainerElement = document.getElementById(elementID); 
    
    if(tableContainerElement !== null){                     // make sure we found it
        HTML += `${createHeader()}<tbody>`;   // Add the header and begin the body
        data.filter(record => filter(record))  // filter records
            .forEach(record => HTML+=createRow(record));    // add filteredrecords
            
        // now put it all together and put it on the page
        tableContainerElement.innerHTML = `<div>${title}</div><table>${HTML}</tbody></table>`;
        return true; // incase you need to know it worked
    }
    return false;

}

// create the click events and have them create the tables they need
document.getElementById("But1").addEventListener("click",
       function(){createTable(
           locSpecs,
           function(record){ 
                return Number(record.SF.replace(",","")) < 1800;
           },
           "SF,YearBuilt,Address".split(","),
           "tableContainer",
           "Records with a SF under 1800"
        );}
     );
document.getElementById("But2").addEventListener("click",
       function(){createTable(
           locSpecs,
           function(record){ 
                return Number(record.YearBuilt) > 1922;
           },
           "SF,YearBuilt".split(","),
           "tableContainer",
           "Records built after 1922"
        );}
     );

document.getElementById("But3").addEventListener("click",
       function(){createTable(
           locSpecs,
           function(record){ 
                return record.YearBuilt === "1922";
           },
           "SF,Address".split(","),  // Dont need year 
           "tableContainer",
           "Records built in 1922"
        );}
     );

         
// show the default table 
createTable(  // display all records and fields
      locSpecs,
      function(){return true; }, // filter function true for all
      "Address,SF,YearBuilt".split(","),
      "tableContainer",
      "All records."
);
```

```css
input {
    cursor:pointer;
}
but:hover {
    background:#7dF;
}
div {
  width:100%;
}
table {
    border:black 2px solid;
    width:100%;
}
thead {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    border:black 1px solid;
}

thead .FF_SF {
    background:#dfffdf;
    text-align:center;
}
thead .FF_YearBuilt {
    background:#efdfff;
    text-align:center;
}
thead .FF_Address {
    background:#ffefdf;
    text-align:center;
}



.FF_Address {
    background:#ffddcc;
}
.FF_SF {
    background:#ccffdd;
    text-align:center;
}
.FF_YearBuilt {
    background:#ddccff;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div>Select an option "Sorry IE ECMAScript6 browsers only."</div>
<input value="SF less than 1800" id="But1">
<input value="Year Over 1922" id="But2">
<input value="Year 1922" id="But3">
<div id='tableContainer'>
```